# Trouble deploying django webapp onto google cloud

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, webdeploy

I've been following the google cloud documentation titled, "[Running Django on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)" . **I'm using the same app provided in the documentation** in the "Cloning the Django App". Honestly, I get lost in the google cloud documentation under the "Configuring Database Settings" section. This what my settings.py (mysite/settings.py in the given app mentioned previously)

[Mysite/settings.py img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvzQv.jpg)

Whenever running *python manage.py makemigrations* - I get the following error message on the CLI...
**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable**

Also, I have noticed there is no .env file in that repo. Would I maybe have to create it myself or would is it fine? Again I am using the github given app via the documentation.

Just trying to deploy Django website to google cloud. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im on Mac Big Sur btw if that matters.

Comment: What happens when you try to deploy? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: @NoCommandLine whenever I try and run the server using 'python manage.py runserver' the error message I receive is...

path/to/django-webapp-test/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python3/django/mysite/settings.py", line 18, in <module>
    import environ
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'environ'

I know environ in that settings.py though you can see on the GH repo mentioned in the original question. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy the application using [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) and got the same error you mentioned about. Then I observed that there is some issue with the github files mentioned in the documentation for which an open [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/6255) is there. The reason for the issue is that the current code in the github repository matches a  new tutorial version and we hope to get the new tutorial version updated soon to match the current code in the github repository.

For now using a specific previous version of  ‘mysite/settings.py’ file in place of the current ‘mysite/settings.py’ file and adding ‘PyMySQL==1.0.2’ in requirements.txt  file will work. The required previous version of the ‘mysite/settings.py’ can be found in [this link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/01828119793ab43afa7ac517716721c16b00e7ee/appengine/standard_python3/django/mysite/settings.py). Follow the documentation for all remaining steps.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for getting back to me and providing some helpful resources and tips on what to do next. Following your tips and the GH forum were extremely helpful. I was able to correct my settings.py and everything. Currently, Im facing the 'Bad Gateway' nginx error when trying to  -- $glcoud app deploy --. Any advice on that would be greatly appreciated too, if you've experienced it I'm about to make another thread for that problem

Comment: Hey. I could see you have created another thread for this error. Also from that thread it seems to me that you are not using the settings.py file I have referred to. Please make sure you are using the correct settings.py file and following the documentation.